# Why did the Basilisk obey Tom Riddle (or anyone)?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, character-motivation, basilisk

Why would the giant, hungry, blood-crazed basilisk obey Tom Riddle or Ginny under his influence, or really anybody, and *not* simply go out and eat on its own?

Comment: This might be a dupe, but I'm not sure

Comment: because it was made to obey the heir of slytherin

Comment: Voldy has a very high charisma score

Answer (score 38):

### Basilisks are controllable by Parselmouths

> The creation of Basilisks has been illegal since medieval times, although the practice is easily concealed by simply removing the chicken egg from beneath the toad when the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures comes to call. However, since **Basilisks are uncontrollable except by Parselmouths**, they are as dangerous to most Dark wizards as to anybody else, and there have been no recorded sightings of Basilisks in Britain for at least four hundred years.
>   <sub>*Fantastic Beast and Where to Find Them* (2001 textbook) - Basilisk</sub>

Comment: "The creation of Basilisks" Wait, one can *create* a Basilisk? I always thought *breed* would be the operative word here.

Comment: @Mast: The real-world legend of the basilisk is about it being hatched by a cockerel from a toad's egg -- i.e., *not* in the "once there were two basilisks who really liked each other" way of things. So "create" is appropriate.

Comment: "Basilisks are uncontrollable except by Parselmouths" - I'm not sure how this answers the question. All this says is that Parselmouths are the only wizards who could control Basilisks. This doesn't say that Basilisks *must* to obey Parselmouths.

Comment: @DevSolar Pretty sure it's a cockerel's egg, hatched by a toad. This'd match the above text (remove from under the toad) and the fact that it couldn't normally happen anyway (Cockerels don't lay).

Comment: @djsmiley2k: Nah, you're thinking of a cockatrix. Mrs. Rowling has been known for playing it loose with the mythology like that.

Comment: @DevSolar re-read the quoted passage please. in particular this bit: The creation of Basilisks has been illegal since medieval times, although the practice is easily concealed by simply removing the **chicken egg** from beneath the **toad**

Comment: @djsmiley2k: Re-read my comment, please. "The **real-world legend** of the basilisk..." -- Mrs. Rowling, for all her commendable work, is not gospel truth on mythology. Basilisks and cockatrix are written about since medieval times.

Comment: Ah you win :P well played!

Comment: @Ellesedil "*Basilisks are uncontrollable except by Parselmouths*" => Parselmouths can **control** Basilisks. **control** (*v.*): determine the behavior or supervise the running of

Comment: @maxathousand that's a logic error. "All non-parselmouths cannot control baselisks" does not imply "All parselmouths can control baselisks." Being a parselmouth can be necessary but not sufficient to control a baselisk.

Comment: @stannius Fair point, I misspoke.

Answer (score 21):

It would appear that snakes *must* listen to what is told to them in Parselmouth. For instance, at the Dueling Club:

> Harry wasn't sure what made him do it. He wasn't even aware of deciding to do it. All he knew was that his legs were carrying him forward as though he was on casters and that he had shouted stupidly at the snake, "Leave him alone!" And miraculously — inexplicably — the snake slumped to the floor.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Chapter 11</sub>

And when Tom Riddle tells the Basilisk to attack Harry, he's *ordering* the snake, and the evidence that we have is that snakes must obey a Parselmouth's *orders*.

Comment: Stop where? What context?

Comment: If snakes must listen to Parseltongues, then couldn't Harry have ordered the Basilisk to stop what it was doing at any given moment?

Comment: He didn't know he could.

Comment: Harry is a parseltongue, it's kind of a major plot device in the story, even in the films.

Comment: Harry was told by Tom Riddle that the Baselisk would only obey the Heir of Slytherin.  Given the situation, I don't think Harry really stopped to try and prove Tom wrong, and he didn't know that part of an heir of Slytherin was in himself so he probably could have controlled it

Comment: Is this really evidence that the snake *has* to obey Harry? Would it really be unreasonable to think that the snake decided to obey Harry of it's own accord?

Comment: @LCIII Tom just grinded the parseltongue skill until he was levelcapped.

Comment: @Ellesedil - that's why we need the Tom/Basilisk scene. Where Tom tells the snake *not to go after what it wants* - Fawkes.

Comment: When I order my kids to stop jumping on the couch and pick up their toys and they obey me, are they compelled to obey me or are they simply choosing to do so? I'm not sure showing serpents obeying Parselmouths is evidence they *have* to obey. I don't really remember the actual text of that scene as it has been several years since I last read the book. But I don't yet see any evidence in these answers that serpents *must* obey a Parselmouth.

Comment: @LCIII I can't recall what happened in the book, but in the movie, Tom Riddle definitely ordered the Basilisk to stop listening to Harry and only listen to himself. "He only listens to *me* now." So Harry could have conceivably done the same thing before Tom if he were a bit smarter.

Comment: @LCIII - have you read the books?

Comment: Tom Riddle lies a lot, in the books, he is almost always lying or being deceitful. We can't talk Tom's words as being truthful. Tom implies that Harry can't control or even reason with the basilisk and Harry didn't try to order the basilisk. According to the FBawtFT book, only parseltongues can control basilisks